# Task.Run equivalent in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, async-await

I am porting .net to silverlight and I have this in .net

```
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        if (Continuation == Sentinel ||
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(
                ref Continuation, continuation, null) == Sentinel)
        {
            //original code in .net
            //Task.Run(continuation);

            //can i use this as Task.Run alternative in silverlight?
            Task.Factory.StartNew(continuation);
        }
    }
```

Silverlight doesnt have Task.Run. Looking at msdn

> The Run method is a simpler alternative to the StartNew method.

Fortunately, Silverlight do have StartNew method.

My question is, can I use StartNew method as Task.Run alternative in Silverlight? Are there anything that i should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Per @svick's note, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) has a discussion of this exact topic.  The key point mentioned there is that `Task.Run(someAction)` is equivalent to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, 
    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

---

Their functions look to be identical, for any purpose I can think of: "schedule this action for execution on the thread pool".

[Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (.Net):

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task handle for that work.

[TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (Silverlight):

> Starts the Task, scheduling it for execution to the current TaskScheduler.

So the latter sounds slightly different, in that it uses a [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but by default the scheduler also just uses the thread pool:

> The default scheduler for Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET Framework ThreadPool to queue and execute work.

Comment: `Task.Run()` also uses a scheduler. The difference is that `StartNew()` uses `TaskScheduler.Current`, while `Run()` uses `TaskScheduler.Default`. Also, `Run()` has overloads for async methods, `StartNew()` doesn't. For more details, see [*Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).